# Is it possible to use Angular Material for an Angular4 app?

Tags: angular, angular-material, hyperledger-composer

I used the hyperledger composer framework to automatically create an Angular application. The version of this Angular App is Angular 4.0.0.

I want to use Angular Material to improve the UI generated by hyperledger composer.

To that end I installed Angular Material, running the command:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

I got the following warnings in the console:

```
npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN @angular/material@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN @angular/material@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So as far as I understand it, I have two options:

option 1:
Upgrade the Angular App (that was automatically generated by hyperledger composer framework) from version 4 to version 6

option 2:
Install an old version of Angular Material that is compatible with Angular4.

Option 1 is not feasible because the code generated by the hyperledger composer framework would not mix with the new APIs of the Angular6 node_modules, correct? Or did the APIs stay the same?

Regarding option 2:

I tried to run

```
npm install --save @angular/material@4
```

in order to install a version of Angular Material that is compatible with Angular4. However, I received the following error message:

```
No matching version found for @angular/material@4
In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Is it possible at all to use Angular Material for an Angular4 app?

Comment: use `2.0.0-beta` version, see https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.12/package.json

Comment: thank you for your comment ... I'm absolutely confused atm, though. I thought the different versions of angular-material correspond to the angular versions? (i.e. I thought angular-material version 4 is for angular4, angular-material version 5 is for angular5, angular-material version6 is for angular6) .... and how would I install the version you mentioned? ... using "npm install --save @angular/material@2.0.0-beta"?

Comment: It should be `npm install --save @angular/material@2.0.0-beta12`

Comment: ok ... and what are the different versions of angular-material, if you don't mind me asking you? Is @angular/material@2.0.0 the newest version? If so, why does it work with Angular4 and the older version of angular/material doesn't work with it?

Comment: There will be breaking changes while angular's version updates, same will happen with material. For changes, you can check https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/5.0.0-rc0/CHANGELOG.md.

Comment: I followed the link you provided - and I'm more confused than before ... did they publish version 2.0.0 of angular-material and then they published version 5.0.0 after that? Why did they jump from 2 to 5 ? And why is there only a beta of version 2? Where is the stable version of it?

Comment: Angular is trying to unify all its packages. This is why they jump from 2 to 5. Stable version of `material` is based on version of `angular` you used. For `angularV4.3.x`,  `@angular/material@2.0.0-beta12` is the right version to use.

Comment: The angular app is version 4.0.0, though ... so I should use angular/material@2.0.0-beta7 , correct? (see https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.7/package.json)

Comment: OK, you have got it. :-)

Comment: ok thank you for your help

Comment: @Pengyy I have now managed to install angular/material but I have one more question: I also need to install angular cdk ... "npm install --save @angular/cdk" results in the following error message: "npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0" .........  But even the oldest version of cdk seems to depends  on angular 6.0.0 (see https://github.com/angular/cdk-builds/blob/master-c880faa/package.json) ... how can I install angular/cdk for my Angular4 app?

Comment: Same way, install `cdk` of the same version.

Comment: running "npm install --save @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.7" results in the error message "No matching version found for @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.7"

Comment: Are you sure you need `cdk` module when using `material@2.0.0-beta7`. I didn't got such warning after installed `material` while trying on my pc.

Comment: I'm not sure I need it ... but usually the two are always installed together